# PHP won't fetch data from database, displays a blank page?

Tags: php, mysql

I just started to learn how to code PHP and MySQL, I apologize to anyone if this is a simple mistake that I've missed. I created a PHP file called index.php, connected to the database successfully but when I try to fetch a username from the users table, I reload index.php and it displays a blank page. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

I've tried different codes - even modified my code using a solution from Stack Overflow that looked right for me but it did nothing...

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "dbUser", "dbPassword", "dbTableName");
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die("There was an error connecting to the database.");
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    print_r($row);
}
```

I wanted to display all users in the table (currently only one).

Comment: You don't know what's wrong because you don't check for errors in your code. Never assume the code is always going to work flawlessly. Use [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to get a detailed error message from the database.

Comment: Sorry, John. Whereabouts do I put that?

Comment: @JordanThompson have a look at this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/debugger.php

Comment: Thanks to you both, I figured it out!